# Keras : How can I "merge" the output of two different neural networks to train a decoder?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have time series which I embed using a CNN.
I also have image-like data which I embed using a RNN.

What I would like to do is merge the output of both encoder networks to train a decoder network which would predict the next timestamp of the input time series.

Would you have any help on how to do this ?

I am using Python (Keras library) on Windows 10.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can be accomplished by building a complex model using the Keras Functional API. The below resource can help you out in understanding about it.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/keras-functional-api-deep-learning/

Note: The main concept you would want to focus on is concatenation of the layers.